# You can vs. You may

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I'm struggling with the use of "can" or "may" in this sentence.

> "Maybe you *can* encounter one of our relatives"

or

> "Maybe you *may* encounter one of our relatives."

Which is correct? Or are both are wrong?

Comment: Can you identify your cause of concern?

Comment: It's a matter of possibility that maybe she will be able to encounter one of my relatives in(for example) Hongkong.

Comment: The difference between "can" and "may" can be (or may be) confusing.  Of the above options, neither is idiomatic.  If you're simply saying a chance meeting might occur you would say "You might (or may) meet (or encounter) one of my relatives" or "Maybe you will meet one of my relatives."  And if you wish the person to look up one of your relatives you would say something like "Maybe you could look up one of my relatives" or "Maybe you could find one of my relatives."  "Encounter" does not imply a planned/intended meeting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Maybe you *can*..." means that person should actively seek out your relatives. "Maybe you *may*..." means they might stumble upon your relatives.

Comment: Still confused.  Maybe you have suggestions of rephrasing it.

Comment: It depends on what you're intending. Very likely, you're meaning that the person is going to a place that your relatives live in, therefore, they might see them. I'm guessing that person will not be actively looking for your relatives; they may just happen upon them. Which means you'd use "may". If they will be searching purposefully for your relatives, use "can". Does that help?